# Странице не найдена

Tags: html

Как сделать так если введёшь после имени домена вашего сайта yoursite.com/здесь пишешь любую белиберду, показывает страницу где отображается текст "страница не найдена !" ???

Comment: Так и будет.
Но вообще, я думаю, Вам про mod_rewrite почитать надо

Comment: Veikedo,всё я уже узнал как надо делать могу сказать,надо в корне сайта создать файл ".htaccess" и написать в этом файле :
ErrorDocument 404 /404errorpage.html
и создать такой файл 404errorpage.html и внутри можно писать что угодно например "страница не найдена".